# Polynomials of integer coefficients that evaluated at Mersenne or Fermat numbers produce square-free integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, polynomials, integer-sequences, square-free

Mersenne numbers $M_n=2^n-1$ and Fermat numbers $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ draw the attention of professional mathematicians to get prime constellations or statements related to primality tests for these sequences.
In next paragraphs of this post I present sequences producing square-free integers when one evaluates $M_n$ or $F_n$ as the argument $x$ in certain polynomials $P(x)$ with  integer coefficients.

**Computational evidence 1.** For $2\leq n\leq 50$ the terms sequences similar than of the sequence *A118558* from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, for example the sequence $(2^n-1)^4-12$, or the sequences $(2^n-1)^4-24$, or $(2^n-1)^4-44$, or $(2^n-1)^4-62$ or $(2^n-1)^4-84$ are square-free integers (these segments of consecutive integers, for each of the mentioned sequences, have no repeated prime numbers).

**Computational evidence 2.** Similarly as a first example, for each integer $0\leq n\leq 7$ the sequence $$F_n^2-2=\left(2^{2^n}+1\right)^2-2$$
is a finite sequence of consecutive square-free integers. Similarly consider sequeces of the form $\left(2^{2^n}+1\right)^{2\kappa}-2$, same segment of integers that I've tested $0\leq n\leq 6$, for $\kappa=2,3,4$.

> **Question (Edited**$^{*}$**).** I would like to know if it is possible to say something about if it is unlikely **A)** to find a polynomial with integer coefficients $P_0\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that *one has* $P_0(M_n)$ *or* $P_0(F_n)$ *have no repeated prime factors* $\forall n\geq n_0$, being $n_0$ a suitable choice of a positive integer; **or B)** to find a polynomial with integer coefficients $P_0\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that *one has that there are infinitely many terms of the sequence* $P_0(M_n)$ *or* $P_0(F_n)$ *without repeated prime factors when* $n\geq 1$ *runs over positive integers.* **Many thanks.**

*I've reformulated the question/post to provide a more concise question. I'm asking for reasonings, heuristic or computational evidence about what work can be done for A) or for B) since I think that these questions can be very difficult to solve, after there are helpful answers I should to accept an answer. That I evoke in my Question B) is like as a relaxation of A), in this B) we ask if there exists a polynomial $P_0(x)$ with integer coefficients for which the sequence $P_0(M_n)$ or the sequence $P_0(F_n)$ produces infinitely many square-free integers (isn't required that are consecutive integers).

### References:

One has for example the Wikipedia articles with titles *Fermat number* and *Square-free integer*, and from Wolfram MathWorld the article with title *Mersenne Number*.

Comment: I've reformulated the question/post to makes it more concise. I'm asking **what work can be done about it**: polynomials with integer coefficients that evaluated at Mersenne or Fermat numbers provides us "many" values without repeated prime factors. I mean reasonings, heuristics or computational evidence that supports your claims about A) or B).

Comment: You can rewrite your evaluations as computing $f(2^n)$ for some polynomial $f$. For fixed $f$ and varying $n$, you can apply the generalization to arbitrarily many summands of the abc conjecture and conclude that the radical of $f(2^n)$ is large, that is, it's mostly squarefree. Of course, the conjecture is open, so that's just a conjectural explanation to a weaker form of what you've observed.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention @FelipeVoloch and help. If you consider it, please expand your comment as an answer, it is appreciate since in this way I can to understand your explanation (I'm not a professional mathematician). I've emphasized in previous days in the body of the post that I'm asking if it is possible to say something about the question A) or the question B).